# How to get the list of files under the directory in a JAR file

Tags: java

I want to know the list of files under the 'META-INF/config' directory in a JAR file.

I am using the below code to retrieve the files list. But it is failing.

```
    Enumeration<URL> path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/config/");
    while(path.hasMoreElements())
    {
      URL path1 = path.nextElement();   
      System.out.println("File =" +path1.getFile());
      File configFolder = new File(path1.getPath());
      File[] files = configFolder.listFiles();
      for (File file : files)
      {
        System.out.println("\nFile Name =" + file.getName());
      }
    }
```

Can somebody help me in fixing this?

Thanks In Advance,
Maviswa

Comment: Does the config folder really exist ? Most JAR files don't have that... Since JAR files are basically ZIP files, open it with an archive utility (like WinRAR) and check.

Comment: Where is there error occuring?  What kind of exception are you getting?  How are you specifying the particular jar file?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.jar.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.io.*;

public class JarContents{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
  JarContents mc = new JarContents();
  }

  public JarContents() throws IOException{
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.print("Enter jar file name: ");
  String filename = in.readLine();
  File file = new File(filename);
  if(!filename.endsWith(".jar")){
  System.out.println("Invalid file name!");
  System.exit(0);
  }
  else if(!file.exists()){
  System.out.println("File not exist!");
  System.exit(0);
  }

  try{
  JarFile jarfile = new JarFile(filename);
  Enumeration em = jarfile.entries();
  for (Enumeration em1 = jarfile.entries(); em1.hasMoreElements();) {
  System.out.println(em1.nextElement());
  }
  }
  catch(ZipException ze){
  System.out.println(ze.getMessage());
  System.exit(0);
  }
  }
}
```

Good Luck!!!

Comment: I provided what I had, which he can use as alternate... if you know, you can fix... OK??

Answer (score 0):

try adding a `"/"` or `"./"` before the META-INF in the `getResources()` call
e.g.
...

```
read.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("./META-INF/config/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember having to do this a while back to read in a jar's manifest.mf to extract its version information to display.  Given that all properly built jars have manifests, trying to access them as a resource is impossible (they all have the same path), and as such, had to examine the jar individually as a zip file.

Given that you aren't providing information as to where the failure is, it is difficult to guess as to what your problem is.  I'm not sure if it is not finding the file that you are expecting, or if it is reading the wrong file, or if you are getting NPEs, etc.